# Dimension of a vector space is even implies Ker T = Im T.

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $ V $ be a vector space space of dimension $ n $ even, then there exists a linear map $T : V \rightarrow V $ such that $ Ker T = Im T $ ? The converse is obviously true.

Comment: Please rephrase the title of the question.

Answer (score 4):

$v_1,...,v_{2n}$ a basis.

$f(v_i)=0$, $i=1,2,...,n$

$f(v_{n+i})=v_i$, $i=1,2,...,n$.

Answer (score 0):

We know that $V/ker(\phi) \cong im(\phi)$.

$dim(V)=2n$, $dim(V/\ker(\phi))=dim(V)-dim(\ker(\phi))=2n-dim(\ker(\phi))=dim(im(\phi))$. You can take $dim(\ker(\phi))=dim( im(\phi))=n$, which implies that $\ker(\phi)=im(\phi)$