# Does there exist a linear operator $T$ on an even-dimensional vector space such that Ker($T$) = Im($T$)?

Tags: linear-algebra

Is it possible to find a linear transformation $T: V \to V$ such that Ker($T$) $=$ Im($T$)?

Of course if V is odd-dimensional then it follows directly from the dimension theorem (that dim Ker($T$) + dim Im($T$) equals the dimension of the domain) that this is impossible, but what if V is even dimensional? There's a similar question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1202655/dimension-of-a-vector-space-is-even-implies-ker-t-im-t) and the person gives as an answer:

Take basis {$v_1,...,v_{2n}$}, define linear transformation:

$f(v_i) = 0, i = 1, 2, ..., n$
$f(v_{n+i}) = v_i, i = 1, 2, ... , n$

Sure this implies dim Ker($T$) = dim Im($T$). But is that the same thing as Ker($T$) $=$ Im($T$)?

Comment: In that specific example, yes. This is because the image, by definition is the span of $v_1,\dots,v_n$. Also, that is the kernel, again by construction, since $v_1,\dots,v_n$ map to zero.

Comment: Just reinforcing Nick's comment. Yes, by construction.

Comment: Oh I see it now.